# associate a character to an abelian extension in local class field theory

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory, class-field-theory, local-field

Let $K_v$ a local and $F$ a finite abelian extension of it.

Two questions:
Could somebody explain how local class field theory
associates naturally a character of $K_v^{\times}$ to $F$.
And, if $r \in K_v$ what is "the order" of $r$ in this character
of $K_v^{\times}$ associated to $F$.

The question arose from terminology used in this [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/463800) (first sentence) by Will Sawin specializing to $K_v= \mathbb{Q}_p$ and $r=p$.

Comment: I think this was answered in the comments of the linked post. Maybe you want to close this question?